# NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule) No provider for x

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am new to Angular and am trying to write unit tests for a feature I recently implemented.  The feature works fine but the unit tests won't even compile due to the following error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[BillingPageComponent -> BillingPageComponent]:
      NullInjectorError: No provider for BillingPageComponent!
```

The stack trace looks like this:

```
      at NullInjector.get (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:8890:27)
      at R3Injector.get (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:9334:33)
      at R3Injector.get (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:9334:33)
      at ChainedInjector.get (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14018:36)
      at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4608:39)
      at getOrCreateInjectable (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4656:12)
      at ɵɵdirectiveInject (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11801:19)
      at NodeInjectorFactory.BillingPaymentComponent_Factory [as factory] (..\..\ng:\BillingPaymentComponent\ɵfac.js:6:58)
      at getNodeInjectable (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:4862:44)
      at createRootComponent (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14273:35)
      at ComponentFactory.create (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:14137:25)
      at initComponent (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:27492:51)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:411:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:300:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:410:56)
      at Object.onInvoke (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:11083:33)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:410:56)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:165:47)
      at NgZone.run (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:10934:28)
      at _TestBedImpl.createComponent (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:27495:41)
      at Function.createComponent (../../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs:27302:37)
      at src/app/pages/billing-page/payment/payment.component.spec.ts:118:23 [<-- This is my spec file]
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:411:30)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:300:43)
      at _ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>._ZoneDelegate.invoke (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:410:56)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone.umd.js:165:47)
      at Object.wrappedFunc (../../node_modules/zone.js/bundles/zone-testing.umd.js:789:34)
```

Based on the error, it would seem that this would be a `TestBed.configureTestingModule` issue.  However, I do, in fact, provide a mocked version of the component (specifically, a 'SpyObj' of component `BillingPaymentComponent`) as shown here in my `beforeEach()` method:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyBillingPageComponent = createSpyObj<BillingPageComponent>('BillingPageComponent', ['goBillingList', 'payNow']);

    spyBillingService = createSpyObj<BillingService>('BillingService', [
      'clearSelected',
      'getPaymentLines',
      'getPaymentTableCells',
      'setComponent',
      'totalAmount',
    ]);

    spyPaymentClient = createSpyObj<PaymentClient>('PaymentClient', ['bank']);
    spyUserContextService = createSpyObj<UserContextService>('UserContextService', ['get']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [BillingPaymentComponent],
      imports: [DXONgSwiftUiModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: BillingPageComponent, useValue: spyBillingPageComponent },
        { provide: BillingService, useValue: spyBillingService },
        { provide: PaymentClient, useValue: spyPaymentClient },
        { provide: UserContextService, useValue: spyUserContextService },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BillingPaymentComponent);
...
```

By the way, the error shown in the stack trace occurs at the last line shown (`fixture = ...`).

If it helps, here are the import statements:

```
import { AccountType } from '@benefitsui/app/api/benefits-enums';
import { PaymentData } from '@benefitsui/app/pages/billing-page/billing-page.types';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BillingPaymentComponent } from '@benefitsui/app/pages/billing-page/payment/payment.component';
import { BillingService } from '@benefitsui/app/pages/billing-page/billing.service';
import { DXONgSwiftUiModule } from '@dxo/ng-swift-ui';
import { SpyObj, createSpyObj } from '@benefits/test-utils';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BillingPageComponent } from '../billing-page.component';
import { PaymentClient } from '@benefitsui/app/api/benefits-clients';
import { UserContextService } from '@benefitsui/app/services/user-context/user-context.service';
import { UserContext } from '@benefitsui/app/services/user-context/user-context.types';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Here is the constructor for the component under test, which shows the dependency injection that occurs:

```
  constructor(
    private billingService: BillingService,
    private formBuilder: UntypedFormBuilder,
    private parent: BillingPageComponent,
    private paymentClient: PaymentClient,
    private userContextService: UserContextService
  ) {}
```

I am on a Windows laptop.  My version of Node is v18.18.2.

Given that the feature itself works fine, I would at least like the unit tests to compile so that I can debug them and provide protection against regressions.

Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: You will definitely want to remove the provider of BillingPageComponent. It should only be in the declarations. I imagine you added that because of the error, which indicates that the component definition is lending towards this in some way. Can you show some of how the component itself is defined? Especially in the @Component area where the selector and templateUrl are. I imagine there is another item in there that will give a clue.

Comment: Wesley, thanks for the comment.  I do, in fact, need the provider for `BillingPageComponent` since there are a few calls to that object that I need to mock.  (The methods I need to mock are shown in the 'SpyObj' creation call.)  Regarding how the component is defined, I added the constructor initialization to my post, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this issue for several days, I found that the issue appears to be a [Red Herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).  The solution turns out to be a pathing issue with the imports.  Specifically, I shifted the relative pathing to absolute pathing, which fixed the entire problem.  Here is the specific fix:

```
...
// import { BillingPageComponent } from '../billing-page.component';
import { BillingPageComponent } from '@benefitsui/app/pages/billing-page/billing-page.component';
...
```

This one fix solves the entire compilation problem.

The real issue here is why this is necessary.  It appears related to the fact that I am developing on a Windows-based machine.  A clue to this solution came from a colleague who downloaded my branch and did NOT have the compilation issue.  (He develops on a Linux-based machine.)

I don't know if this is an issue with the mocking library built into Angular or if it is an issue inherent with Microsoft pathing.  Either way, though, this turned out to be a very frustrating and time-consuming bug that had nothing to do with the reported error so I wanted to share my solution to save other developers the same heartache I experienced.